# Interactive diagram in a website : What do I need to learn ? Which tools do I need to use?

Tags: user-interface, web, diagram

Complete beginner. I want to make a website that provides 2D maps of an online game, in the form of interactive diagrams.

Something that looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIgvl.png

Thanks to a secure authentication system, clicking on a location on the website would trigger a certain action in the game client.

What do I need to learn to :

- Draw diagrams with nodes and lines connecting the nodes
- Make nodes interactive betweeen the website and the game client

I have started looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML, I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easiest way to do that would be an [image-map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp), but this is only applicable if your map is a static image which doesn't change dynamically. It's basically just an image and you can define areas where you can e.g. add a click-event with javascript.

If you need to do more complex things, I would suggest looking into [html canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp) and [svg](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp).

And if you don't wan't to invent the wheel completely new by yourself, here is a nifty javascript framework:
[gojs](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/) or [d3](https://d3js.org/)

Comment: image-map seems to be exactly what's needed here. Thanks !

Comment: please accept the answer to close the question - thanks :)